# How to get UserID from Entity Framework/Wcf Service in Delete trigger in DB?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

Suppose I have a table say MyTab(ID, ..., UserID) with the data like

```
(ID=1, ..., UserID =123)
```

Then With SL app + WCF Ria Service + EF, a user with UserID = 456 to run the app and try to delete the above one row data. What I did is remove the entity instance from entityset with wcf ria service, then SubmitChanges. Code like:

```
 mytab.UserID = 456;
 context.MyTabs.Remove(mytab);
 context.SubmitChanges(....);
```

but in Delete trigger, I can't get the data UserID = 456 because this is delete, not update. 
How to get UserID =456 in delete trigger for this case?

Comment: what do you mean with Delete trigger? Do you mean the Delete method of your DomainService?

Comment: Delete Trigger in database on table MyTab